# Как сделать, чтобы текст обтекал картинку слева

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы картинка обтекала лист `<ul>` справа (каждая строчка должна упираться в картинку справа ), чтобы текст вплотную прилегал к ней?

```css
img.bioPhoto {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="bioCont">
      <ul class="bioContL">
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem odit doloremque illum nemo quibusdam repellendus fugit vero, ducimus corrupti ipsum ipsa est odio beatae, aut similique ad tempore placeat id?</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iure doloribus possimus autem, odio aperiam accusantium! Laborum sunt vero iusto assumenda architecto inventore? Sint officiis ipsam delectus, natus sit accusantium!</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illum magnam, ipsa cumque vero reprehenderit sed fuga iste, neque alias nam tempora ex expedita id inventore aliquid repellat aperiam reiciendis?</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure eligendi nemo similique numquam.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt facere maiores tenetur repellendus consequatur numquam.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet vel consequatur amet et eaque, quam illum nostrum enim error distinctio, soluta eum tempora? Nesciunt laborum dicta distinctio. Distinctio, a harum.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illum magnam, ipsa cumque vero reprehenderit sed fuga iste, neque alias nam tempora ex expedita id inventore aliquid repellat aperiam reiciendis?</li>
        <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
        <img class="bioPhoto" src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-images/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```css
img.bioPhoto {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="bioPhoto" src="//i.imgur.com/w0cvgoX.jpg">
<ul class="bioContL">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem odit doloremque illum nemo quibusdam repellendus fugit vero, ducimus corrupti ipsum ipsa est odio beatae, aut similique ad tempore placeat id?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum iure doloribus possimus autem, odio aperiam accusantium! Laborum sunt vero iusto assumenda architecto inventore? Sint officiis ipsam delectus, natus sit accusantium!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illum magnam, ipsa cumque vero reprehenderit sed fuga iste, neque alias nam tempora ex expedita id inventore aliquid repellat aperiam reiciendis?</li>
  <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
  <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In iure eligendi nemo similique numquam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt facere maiores tenetur repellendus consequatur numquam.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet vel consequatur amet et eaque, quam illum nostrum enim error distinctio, soluta eum tempora? Nesciunt laborum dicta distinctio. Distinctio, a harum.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A illum magnam, ipsa cumque vero reprehenderit sed fuga iste, neque alias nam tempora ex expedita id inventore aliquid repellat aperiam reiciendis?</li>
  <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да спс, поч этого нигде нету, что КАРТИНКУ НУЖНО СТАВИТЬ ПЕРЕД ТЕКСТОМ

Comment: Чёт пару сайтов с "документацией" глянул и только [в примерах](https://learn.javascript.ru/float#tekst-s-kartinkami) это показывается